# Instanciate prefab as child in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

i want a `gameObject` to add instanciatetd objects prom a prefab as his chiled.
so i wrote this code:

```
public class TgtGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

public SpriteRenderer spriteTgt;

public Sprite[] targets;public SpriteRenderer spriteTgt;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    generateRandTgt ();
}


void generateRandTgt(){
    SpriteRenderer tgt = GameObject.Instantiate (spriteTgt, getRandPosition (), Quaternion.identity)as SpriteRenderer;
    tgt.sprite = randSprite ();
}


Sprite randSprite(){
    var length = targets.Length-1;
    Debug.Log (Random.Range(0,length));
    return targets[Random.Range(0,length)];
}


Vector3 getRandPosition(){
    float xScale = gameObject.transform.localScale.x / 2;
    float yScale = gameObject.transform.localScale.y / 2;

    float x = Random.Range(-xScale,xScale);
    float y = Random.Range(-yScale,yScale);
    float z = 0;

    return new Vector3 (x, y, z);
}
```

the instantiated object is getting his size from the prefab like i wanted to.
but the problem is it instanciated at the root node of the hirarchy so they are not placed inside of the gameobject coordinate like i wanted to.

when i am adding this line of code just after the instaciate line :

```
tgt.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
```

it generated as a child like i wanted to but it gets huge and upside down.
how should i manage this?

Comment: what do you mean by huge and upside down

Comment: check if parent gameobject is Scaled or Rotate,if So that Effects The Child gameobjects

Comment: @MasihAkbari if i want the instanciated prefab to be a child but with his own scaling but with the rotation of his father? how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using This To Force Child To Have It's Own Scale After Being a Child:

```
var localScale = child.transform.localScale; // store original localScale value
child.transform.parent = parent;
child.transform.localScale = localScale; // force set
```